# How to get minified version of jQuery UI with npm

Tags: jquery-ui, npm

I've been trying to use NPM to get the minified version of jQuery UI for a project, but it seems like jQuery UI hasn't provided a minified version to NPM (because no minified file appears in the `node_modules/jquery-ui` folder when I run `npm install`).

How can I get the minified version of jQuery UI once I have installed it locally using NPM?

Comment: Typically, you would minify it yourself, together with the rest of your code, using Gulp or Grunt or WebPack.

Comment: If I use Grunt to minify jQueryUI then do I have to update my code whenever jQueryUI updates its library?

Comment: You should use Grunt as part of your build process, and minify all of your code together.

Comment: Use bower and get your minified version :p

Answer (score 0):

i has been solve with install `jquery-ui` version `1.10.5`,

`jquery-ui` version `1.12.0` is not install `minified`